# javascript random pick variable

Tags: javascript, random

How can I make javascript randomly choose between two buttons to click?

```
var $1Button = $('#1'),
    $2Button = $('#2');

function startQuiz(){
  $1Button.trigger('click');
}
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML you are trying to interact?

Comment: Why?.... Can't you just call function that "starts quiz" directly (possibly with some random argument)?

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to handle this situation is to place your two buttons in an array and pick a random index in that array to trigger the click. As an added bonus, the code will easily expand to more than two buttons.

```
var $buttons = [$('#1'), $('#2')];

function startQuiz(){
  var buttonIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * $buttons.length)
  $buttons[buttonIndex].trigger('click');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a function that can basically flip a coin and give you a 0 or 1, true or false, etc. It would probably be easiest to build an array of your elements, generate a random array index, find the element in the array and then trigger the click:

```
var buttons = [$('#1'), $('#2')];

function getRandomButton() {
    return buttons[Math.floor(Math.random() * buttons.length)];
}

function startQuiz(){
    getRandomButton().trigger('click');
}
```